# What fonts are installed on my box?

Tags: fonts

How can I find out which fonts are currently available in my TeX installation? (I'm using a Mac, OS 10.6.x, if that matters, although I'd prefer a machine-independent TeX-based answer). Thanks.

As a followup, I tried googling for an answer to this question, without much success. Is there somewhere I could have looked for myself?

Comment: Refer to [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document) → "Finding the font name" -- which answer depends on whether you're using LaTeX/PDFLaTeX/XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There isn't a definitive "these are the fonts installed" reference, but you can usually discover them by poking around in your TeX distribution. For example, look in /usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf-dist/fonts/ ; you'll find a bunch of subdirectories with type1 fonts, tfm files, and so on. To load a font in LaTeX, however, you need .fd files, and these are found alongside any .sty files for the fonts. For example, t1lmr.fd is the font definition for loading the Latin modern roman fonts with \fontfamily{lmr} (assuming the T1 encoding).

Anyway, the directory names for the fonts themselves will give you clues about packages to load if you're using LaTeX; otherwise, any font with a tfm file (such as ec-lmr10.tfm for Latin modern roman at 10pt) can be loaded in plain TeX with

```
\font\tenrm=ec-lmr10 at 10pt
```

You might font individual font packages easier to locate by browsing through CTAN, since the support files will be located alongside the fonts themselves.

**Update**

You could grep through the LaTeX support files to find a comprehensive listing of available font families, if you liked; not sure how useful this is, but try:

```
 find /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ -name '*.fd' | xargs grep '\\DeclareFontFamily' | sed 's#.*\\DeclareFontFamily{\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)}{\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)}.*#  \1    \2#'
```

(My shell scripting skills are a little rusty, but you get the idea.) Change the first `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` into, say, `T1` if you want only fonts with that encoding.

Comment: It's unfortunate that there's no way to get the LaTeX-available font-family names. Seems like a useful thing to have (at least for me).

Comment: Shell script looks fine but I'd put single quotes around `*.fd`.

Comment: @gknauth I'm sure you're correct but could you also explain why?

Comment: `'*.fd'` lets `find` do the expansion, whereas `*.fd` has the shell do the expansion, and if there are too many files, the whole thing could fail.

Comment: @gknauth, @Will: I agree that the pattern `*.fd` should be enclosed in single quotes, but I don't think gknauth's reason is fully correct. Without quotes the shell will try to expand the pattern. This will break if there are any files ending with `.fd` in the _current directory_.

Comment: One can use `locate` instead of `find`+`grep`. For example, `locate -A *.fd T2A` prints a list of `.fd`-files with T2A in name. Anyway, thsnks for idea!

Answer (score 25):

Besides searching for font files with the appropriate extension or looking below the texmf-dist/fonts/ directory, I would check the font map files.

This command gives an system wide overview of the active and inactive font map files:

```
updmap-sys --listmaps
```

Use it at the command prompt. The output looks like:

```
Map      euler.map
MixedMap cm.map
MixedMap cmextra.map
MixedMap cyrillic.map
MixedMap symbols.map
Map bera.map
MixedMap cm-super-t1.map
MixedMap cm-super-t2a.map
MixedMap cm-super-t2b.map
MixedMap cm-super-t2c.map
MixedMap cm-super-ts1.map
MixedMap cm-super-x2.map
Map cmcyr.map
Map dstroke.map
Map fourier-utopia-expert.map
Map fourier.map
Map kpfonts.map
Map libertine.map
Map lm.map
MixedMap lxfonts.map
Map marvosym.map
Map MnSymbol.map
Map charter.map
...
```

So I know among others there are installed: euler, cm-super, dstroke, fourier, kpfonts, libertine, marvosym, MnSymbol, charter, etc.

For a reference of `updmap-sys` or `updmap` go to the command prompt (terminal) and type

```
man updmap-sys
```

or for a brief overview

```
updmap-sys --help
```

or have a look at [this web manpage](http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/linuxcommand.org/man_pages/updmap1.html).

Comment: +1 Stefan.  I was going to add a comment to Will's answer about `ls -lr`'ing / `dir /S`'ing the `texmf` for `.map`'s then `grep`'ing them for `^map` or `mixedmap`. But your answer is *way* more elegant! Sadly (for me), `updmap-sys` is not part of MikTeX, and `updmap` itself doesn't provide this function.  Heck, it's back to `dir /s \*.map` I go. :)

Comment: this should the accepted answer for the question!

Answer (score 16):

The above solutions make more sense depending on what you want to do, but the output can be confusing, since it includes things like symbol-only fonts, and doesn't actually show you what the fonts look like or even what their full names are.

I find that if I have a complete, up-to-date installation of TeXlive, however, that the fonts I can choose from (unless I've installed my own custom package) are usually pretty much exactly the ones listed in the [LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) online, and that's usually my go-to source if I'm trying to decide between fonts on aesthetic grounds alone.

Of course, there are other reasons I might want a font list where Stefan's or Will's methods would be more appropriate.

Comment: That's probably the best way to go, really.

Answer (score 11):

On modern Linux systems there's an incredibly useful set of cli tools provided by the Fontconfig (http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/) package. These
include fonts for quering installed fonts, scanning directories for fonts, printing
information about the contents of font files, testing the fonts matched by a given 
name and others, they are a complete lifesaver and along with fontconfig's other
capabilities (Defining user-wide substitutions of fonts very flexibally) turns what
once was very painful into a relatively easy and managable process.

Specifically, the `fc-list` command shows you the paths system-wide installed fonts
and `fc-query` lets you find the proper font fnaily name to use with fontspec.

I use these all the time with xelatex, relying heavily on system fonts rather then
fonts available through my TexLive install.

Answer (score 6):

I can't offer a TeX distribution independent answer as requested but, as some great but nevertheless distribution specific answers have already been provided, I won't feel too out of place about filling in the gaps for MikTeX distro users.  It's as easy-as in MikTeX -- load up Package Manager (Admin), click the Category column header to sort on that field, check out the "Installed On" date in the `\Fonts\METAFONT` and `\Fonts\Outline fonts` categories.  Repeat the process with Package Manager (User) for local configs.

Unfortunately, despite its simplicity, this approach is not a perfect bet; there are still some  big 'ifs' involved:

- it doesn't tell you anything about "non-packaged" fonts (for that, you'll need to run  solutions closer to the metal, as already mentioned, e.g., by Will)
- it doesn't tell you anything about "hand installed" fonts (ditto above)
- it doesn't say anything PSNFSS standard fonts (however, let's assume you at least have these)

Nevertheless, for those with MikTeX, it'll take less than a minute to complete, and it can take them quite a long way to their goal.  Besides being super quick and simple, you can right-click on any entry in Package Manager, click on Properties, to see the detailed description bundled with the package, whether installed on the box or not.

Answer (score 0):

With TeX Live and MiKTeX, you can use

```
albatross -tdb0 a | tail -n+6
```

which gives a nice output similar to:

```
Name: 0swald Bold
Type: Type 1
Files:
- /usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/oswald/0swald-Bold.pfb

Name: 0swald ExtraLight Regular
Type: Type 1
Files:
- /usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/oswald/0swald-ExtraLight.pfb

...
```

This also includes system fonts, which is good if you are using XeTeX or LuaTeX. If you want only LaTeX fonts, you have to filter the texmf tree directories. For a standard TeX Live setup, you can do this with:

```
albatross -tdb0 a | tail -n+6 | awk '{FS=":"; OFS=":"; RS="\n\n"; ORS="\n\n"} /texmf-dist/'
```

The result is pretty much the same, except you are omitting records where there's no `/texmf-dist/` in file paths.

For more options, see [albatross](https://www.mankier.com/1/albatross) man page.