# structured overview of installed fonts suitable for font comparison

Tags: fonts

How to get a "reasonably structured" overview of the fonts installed on a computer that are usable by (La)TeX or alternatively by LuaTeX / XeTeX? By "reasonably structured" overview I imagine a document with a list of fonts (names, basic information, font samples of a user defined template) where fonts are grouped by certain criteria. The desired properties of the font overview are:

1. the groups are not too large (more or less balanced in size),
2. the overview can be created on the own computer (using only fonts available for traditional TeX or LuaTeX / XeTeX), and
3. the overview has the possibility to use own sample text (and own font size if the fonts allow).

Here is an "example" of what I am looking for:

```
    Classification of fonts by *Vox-ATypI*

      -=  Table of Contents  =-
1 Classicals
    1.1 Humanist
          Centaur, Cloister, ...
    1.2 Garalde
          Bembo, Garamond, ...
    1.3 Transitional
          Baskerville, Times Roman, ...
2 Moderns
...

1 Classicals
============

1.1 Humanist
------------
Centaur                ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ, abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
B. Rogers, 1914        wxyz, 1234567890
aka. Metropolitan      sample text using font Centaur

Cloister               ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,  abcdefghijklmnopq
font info              rstuvwxyz, 1234567890
extra info             sample text using font Cloister

...
```

---

For creating such an overview on the own computer, I know of the following two related topics:

1. long **lists of (almost) all fonts** installed on a computer which do *not* show the font characteristics

   - for LaTeX, see [Stefan Kottwitz's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12889) to the question "[Is there a list available for all TeX fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12887/is-there-a-list-available-for-all-tex-fonts)" using ".map" files; and [Will Robertson's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2307) to "[What fonts are installed on my box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/what-fonts-are-installed-on-my-box)" using ".fd" files and just showing "short hands";
   - for LuaTeX / XeTeX (especially OpenType, TrueType), see [this description, part "Finding the name of the font"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37251) simply listing the files of certain font directories;
2. showing all **glyphs of one font**, which is very detailed and a comparison between fonts seems hard at first sight

   - for (La)TeX, one can display the 256 glyphs of a font by `tex testfont` (see http://tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html),
   - for LuaTeX, XeTeX, one can use an approach of "[Generating a table of glyphs with XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23863/generating-a-table-of-glyphs-with-xetex)",
   - external programs like [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/) (which can do much more than just viewing a font);

In general for grouping, I have seen different **classifications of fonts**:
[Styles of Typefaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Style_of_typefaces),
[Vox-ATypI classification / "Typeface Classifications British Standards 2961"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vox-ATypI_classification),
[German Typeface Classification (in German)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_16518), 
Aldo Novarese's "Classificazione Novarese" ([in Italian](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldo_Novarese#La_classificazione_dei_caratteri) or [in German](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldo_Novarese#Schriftenklassifizierungssystem)),
[Electronic Publishing by Wolfgang Beinert (in German)](http://www.typolexikon.de/m/matrix-beinert-schriftklassifikation.html),
or an overview "[How to Classify all of these Thousands of Faces?](http://www.designhistory.org/Type_milestones_pages/TypeClassifications.html)".

---

The following **examples** come close to what I am looking for. All these lists are not restrictable nor expandable to fonts on the own computer.

1. [Samples of serif typefaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_serif_typefaces) and other [Typeface samples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Typeface_samples)

   `(-)` fonts available for LaTeX: unknown / possibly not;
   `(+)` comparison of fonts: good, reasonable long samples;
   `(O)` subclassification is stated, but sorting by that not available;
2. [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) is using a classification similar to [Styles of Typefaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Style_of_typefaces)

   `(+)` fonts available for LaTeX: yes;
   `(-)` comparison of fonts: not so easy since font samples in overview are short (e.g., no numbers);
   `(-)` the *large* classes of serif and sans serif fonts are missing subclassification like [this for serif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif#Classification) or [this for sans serif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans_serif#Classification);
3. entries under "Font samplers" at http://tug.org/fonts/

   `(+)` fonts available for LaTeX: yes;
   `(O)` comparison of fonts: sometimes possible with good samples and additional information;
   `(O)` overview often restricted to certain fonts;

Is there something similar that also *satisfies my desired properties*? Otherwise, is there a list or database (similar to [this list of typefaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces)) with which one can easily create such a document?

Comment: I doubt that you can automate this entirely. I’m sure, you can make latex search for all fonts and have them printed with a nice example (like with package `fontbook`). But how should it make the classification? In theory fonts have such information in the os/2 table but only few free fonts have I seen to this day that contain them.

Comment: @georgd Thx. Yes, something like `fontbook` is for XeTeX but automated. If there is nothing ready-made, then for the automation, I am looking for something like a database that can be used to get the classification into TeX & Co. (I mentioned a yet-not-perfect "database" at the end of my question.)

Comment: Such database is perhaps a task for some huge collaborative project. What might be interesting in this context is the Klingspor-Museum’s digital archives (only german as it seems): www.klingspor-museum.de/Kuenstler

Comment: As the comments indicate, this is really too big a job to be automated and not really a good fit for a Q&A format.