# How can I list all the Chinese fonts I have installed? (Ubuntu, TexLive)

Tags: fonts, texlive, languages

I am using package xeCJK and I need to do a `\setCJKmainfont{}` command but I don't even know which fonts I have available on my system.  I have quickly installed a bunch of Chinese fonts but I can't recall what I have installed...

Comment: If you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you can use every font install on your system. It's a lot, You should add what kind of TeX engine you use I think `;-)`

Comment: I'm using TexLive, and XeLatex.  I need a way to see the fonts I have... I'm pretty sure I have the fonts installed, I just need a way to list them and try them systematically...

Comment: You can look at it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/what-fonts-are-installed-on-my-box for a first idea

Comment: Alright, I solved my problem anyway.  I looked in `/usr/share/fonts` and found `ukai.ttc`, then I use `/setCJKmainfont{ukai.ttc}` and it worked.  At first the error was because I didn't use full file-name with extension.

Comment: Try `fc-list :lang=zh`

Answer (score 9):

To find out what Chinese font you have in your laptop, bring up the terminal and execute

```bash
fc-list :lang=zh-cn > chinese.txt
```

a text file named `chinese.txt` will be produced in current directory, with all Chinese font listed.

If a `utf8 ignorance` error is reported, run the following **first**

```bash
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Finally, if you feel like **sorting** the font names

```bash
fc-list :lang=zh-cn | awk -F ": " '{for (f = 2; f <= NF; ++f) { if (f != 2) {printf("%s", OFS);} printf("%s", $f)}; printf "\n"}' | sort -d > chinese.txt
```

Comment: How to use this command in the current directory and display only the font file name (with or without full path) ?

Comment: @maxagaz What do you mean by current directory? I think this can be used in any directory. As for the displaying only the font name, I have updated in the answer.